# OCaml How to reverse only even values in list

Tags: ocaml

I want to transefer something like this:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

into

```
[6,1,4,3,2,5,0,7]
```

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want the even *items* or the items at *even positions* to be reversed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a draft, that reverses the *elements at even positions* (which is what I assume you meant by your question). This is probably far from optimal (e.g. you should make `split` and `join` tail-recursive):

```
let rec split = function
| [] -> [],[]
| h::[] -> [h],[]
| x::y::t -> let a,b = split t in x::a, y::b;;

let rec join a b = match a,b with
| [],_ -> b
| _,[] -> a
| ha::ta,hb::tb -> ha::hb::(join ta tb);;

let doit l = let a,b = split l in join a (List.rev b);;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to reverse the numbers that are actually even, and not just at even positions in the list, the trick is to know where they go. So let's map each element in the list with its position.

```
# let lst = [0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7];;
val lst : int list = [0; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7]
# let lst' = List.mapi (fun i x -> (i, x)) lst;;
val lst' : (int * int) list =
  [(0, 0); (1, 1); (2, 2); (3, 3); (4, 4); (5, 5); (6, 6); (7, 7)]
```

Now we can partition the list based on whether the value is even.

```
# let is_even x = x mod 2 = 0;;
val is_even : int -> bool = <fun>
# let (evens, odds) = List.partition (fun (_, x) -> is_even x) lst';;
val evens : (int * int) list = [(0, 0); (2, 2); (4, 4); (6, 6)]
val odds : (int * int) list = [(1, 1); (3, 3); (5, 5); (7, 7)]
```

Now, let's take the `evens` and get the indexes and the values.

```
# let even_indexes = List.map fst evens
let even_vals = List.map snd evens;;
val even_indexes : int list = [0; 2; 4; 6]
val even_vals : int list = [0; 2; 4; 6]
```

And we'll combine them back together, but with the even values reversed.

```
# let evens' = List.combine even_indexes (List.rev even_vals);;
val evens' : (int * int) list = [(0, 6); (2, 4); (4, 2); (6, 0)]
```

Now, if we append the evens and the odds, and then sort based on the indexes:

```
# let lst'' = List.sort (fun a b -> compare (fst a) (fst b)) (evens' @ odds);;
val lst'' : (int * int) list =
  [(0, 6); (1, 1); (2, 4); (3, 3); (4, 2); (5, 5); (6, 0); (7, 7)]
```

Now, we just need to map out the second value in each tuple.

```
# List.map snd lst'';;
- : int list = [6; 1; 4; 3; 2; 5; 0; 7]
```

Problems are easier to solve when they are broken down into smaller problems.